# Accessing a multidimensional array from a parent each's id in Handlebars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have the data:

```
priceGroups:
[
  {
    label: 'rate1",
    price: 1.00,
    numPeople: 1
  },
  {
    label: 'rate 2",
    price: 2.00,
    numPeople: 2
  },
  {
    label: 'rate 3",
    price: 15.00,
    numPeople: 4
  },
];
```

and

```
labels:
[
  'Solo',
  'Duo',
  'Trio'
  '4 People',
  '5 People
];
```

I want to be able to do this:

```
{{#priceGroups}}
   {{for (a = 1; a <= {{this.numPeople}}; ++a)}}
      <th>{{label[a]}}</th>
   {{/for}}
{{/priceGroups}}
```

I have tried so much and nothing works.

Please help. It is important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just use this:

```
{{#each priceGroups}}<th>{{label}}</th>{{/each}}
```

The `{{#each priceGroups}}` gets you an iteration of the `priceGroups` array and then each item of the array (which is an object) is presented to the template one after another so you can then reference the `{{label}}` property in that object.

You don't embed javascript directly into handlerbars templates like you're trying to do.